# Postgresql Where Specific Time On Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've table structure like this:

```
---------------------------
No | Data | create_time 
---------------------------
1 | Data1 | 2020-04-28 00:01:30
2 | Data2 | 2020-04-28 13:04:00
3 | Data3 | 2020-04-27 01:01:30
4 | Data4 | 2020-04-27 14:04:00
```

How to query But with condition: Date 27 April Until 28 April And Time 00:00 Until 12:00
What I've tried so far:

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ((date(create_time) >= '2020-04-27' AND date(2020-04-27) <= '2020-04-28'
                    AND TO_CHAR(create_time,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '12:00:00'))
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ((date(create_time) >= '2020-04-27' AND date(2020-04-27) <= '2020-04-28'
                        AND TO_CHAR(create_time,'HH24:MI:SS') =>'00:00:00' AND TO_CHAR(create_time,'HH24:MI:SS') <= '12:00:00'))
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to get the data from that date but the time is only on 00:00:00 until 12:00:00 (24 Hours Format)
But it's still not working, The Date is correct but the time that I want is not.

Comment: What data type is `create_time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answer assumes that `create_time` is correctly defined as `timestamp`.

You can combine conditions on the date and time part:

```
select *
from mytable
where create_time::date between date '2020-04-27'and date '2020-04-28'
  and create_time::time between time '00:00' and time '12:00'
```

Alternatively you can use a range condition without casting the column:

```
select *
from mytable
where create_time >= date '2020-04-27'
  and create_time < date '2020-04-29'
  and create_time::time between time '00:00' and time '12:00'
```

That can use an index on `create_time`.

If you don't want to include times at precisely 12:00, you need to change the "time" condition as well:

```
  and create_time::time >= time '00:00'
  and create_time::time < time '12:00'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1912b67eecee2e1ef84e2ad94e9e595b)

Comment: @Abelisto: you are right, but then you shouldn't use `between`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifaEgGwwv1UNKcadbip4R4/3).

```
with cte as
(
    select 
        *,
        cast (create_time::timestamp as time) as hour
    from times
)

select
    no, 
    data
from cte
where date(create_time) >= '2020-04-27'
and date(create_time) <= '2020-04-28'
and hour between '00:00:00' and '12:00:00'
```

Output:

```
| No| Data |  
*----------*
|1 | Data1 | 
|3 | Data3 |
```

Comment: Sorry, what I want to achieve is condition on where clause. I've updated my question

Comment: @JafranJS I have provided you an example. please take a look and let me know if it won't work for you.